# My header title flickering in react native expo when keyboard shows up

Tags: react-native, header, keyboard, expo, stack-navigator

this video describes my problem 
video https://gofile.io/?c=oTpNjA

so when the textInput is focused the header title and left image moves from their positions little up then they goes back to normal. to me it happens in every nested stackNavigator inside a MaterialBottomTabNavigator

My Code

render() {
    return (

```
        value={this.state.address.title}
        onChangeText={title => this.setState({ address: { ...this.state.address, title: title, } })}
        placeholder={i18n.translations[I18nManager.isRTL].Title}
        autoCapitalize='none'
        onSubmitEditing={() => { this.secondTextInput.focus(); }}

      />


      <TouchableOpacity onPress={(e) => {

        this.onShow()
      }}>

        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}

          textAlign={I18nManager.isRTL ? 'right' : 'left'}
          value={this.getText(this.state.address.cityId)}
          onChangeText={cityId => this.setState({ address: { ...this.state.address, cityId: cityId, } })}
          placeholder='   cityId'
          autoCapitalize='none'
          editable={false}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        textAlign={I18nManager.isRTL ? 'right' : 'left'}
        value={this.state.address.street}
        onChangeText={street => this.setState({ address: { ...this.state.address, street: street } })}
        placeholder={i18n.translations[I18nManager.isRTL].Street}
        autoCapitalize='none'
        ref={(input) => { this.secondTextInput = input; }}
        onSubmitEditing={() => { this.thirdTextInput.focus(); }}
      />

      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        textAlign={I18nManager.isRTL ? 'right' : 'left'}
        value={this.state.address.block}
        onChangeText={block => this.setState({ address: { ...this.state.address, block: block } })}
        placeholder={i18n.translations[I18nManager.isRTL].Block}
        autoCapitalize='none'
        ref={(input) => { this.thirdTextInput = input; }}
        onSubmitEditing={() => { this.forthTextInput.focus(); }}
      />

      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        textAlign={I18nManager.isRTL ? 'right' : 'left'}
        value={this.state.address.jadah}
        onChangeText={jadah => this.setState({ address: { ...this.state.address, jadah: jadah } })}
        placeholder={i18n.translations[I18nManager.isRTL].Jadah}
        autoCapitalize='none'
        ref={(input) => { this.forthTextInput = input; }}
        onSubmitEditing={() => { this.fifthTextInput.focus(); }}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        textAlign={I18nManager.isRTL ? 'right' : 'left'}
        value={this.state.address.buidling}
        onChangeText={buidling => this.setState({ address: { ...this.state.address, buidling: buidling } })}
        placeholder={i18n.translations[I18nManager.isRTL].Building}
        autoCapitalize='none'
        ref={(input) => { this.fifthTextInput = input; }}
        onSubmitEditing={() => { this.sixthTextInput.focus(); }}
      />

      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        textAlign={I18nManager.isRTL ? 'right' : 'left'}
        value={this.state.address.floor}
        onChangeText={floor => this.setState({ address: { ...this.state.address, floor: floor } })}
        placeholder={i18n.translations[I18nManager.isRTL].Floor}
        autoCapitalize='none'
        ref={(input) => { this.sixthTextInput = input; }}
      />

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.location} onPress={() => {
        this.GoToLocation()
      }}>
        <Text style={styles.locationText}>{i18n.translations[I18nManager.isRTL].Location</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.save} onPress={() => {
        this.SaveAddress()
      }}>
        <Text style={styles.saveText}>{i18n.translations[I18nManager.isRTL].Save}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>
)
```

}
}

Comment: Going to need more code to go on. Take some time to build a minimal repro and if that doesn't reveal the issue then post the repro cod and I will be happy to take a look. To start, remove all inputs except one and see if you are still getting the problem.

Comment: thanks, i found the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT: i found a solutions for this problem.***

adding this in StackNavigator
`headerForceInset:{top:'never' , bottom:'never'}`
solved the flickering problem but the layout was not ok. So, i needed to add some style

```
  UserProfile: {
      screen: UserProfile ,
      navigationOptions: ()=>({
        headerTitle: i18n.translations[I18nManager.isRTL].Profile,
        headerTintColor:'#99BFC4' ,
        headerTitleStyle: { marginTop:44, height: 44  },
        headerForceInset:{top:'never' , bottom:'never'},
        headerStyle: {
          height: 88,
           backgroundColor:'white',
         }, 

      })
    }
```